# Interstitial Ad - After time and only at game over screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
public class AdCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float timer;
    private string Game_ID = "xxxxx";
    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize(Game_ID,true);        
    }
    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;       
    }
    public static void ShowAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady() && timer <= 0)
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
            timer = 45.0f; 
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to add Interstitial ads to my game but i want to make it show Interstitial Ad after last ad shown 45 seconds ago or game started 45 seconds ago but only at game over screen, i am very novice guy in coding, i am trying to do that in C#.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to share what you tried about the struggle

Comment: Hello, thanks for welcoming. I know how to add Interstitial ads to my game but i want to make it show Interstitial Ad after last ad shown 45 seconds ago or game started 45 seconds ago but only at game over screen, i am very novice guy in coding, i am trying to do that in C#

Comment: Can you be more specific? Like is this Android App or Unity Game, or something else?

Comment: It's a Unity Game, im updating my code at first post